# segregating non-shared data on separate cache lines

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, optimization, multicore

I am aware that as general technique for improving app performance it is advisable to design a structure so that non-shared members (across threads) are located on separate cache lines. This way there won't be no `false sharing` and memory access by each thread will be more efficient.

I wanted to test weather this is true so I did the following small test by changing my guinea-pig structure.

```
struct SharedSlow {
  int a_;  
  int b_;   
  int c_;
  int d_;
};

struct SharedQuick {
  int a_ __attribute__((aligned(32)));
  int d_ __attribute__((aligned(32)));
  int b_ __attribute__((aligned(32)));
  int c_ __attribute__((aligned(32)));
};
```

After switching the test data structure into 'SharedQuick' the thread 'writer_b' will read/write on members `b_ and c_` that are now on a cache line different where `a_ and d_` are (thread 'writer_a' takes care of these last 2).

The result I got is pretty bad: the performance is worst compared to the case where all members are on the same cache line.

Measured with `time`

```
// Shared Slow
real    0m2.063s
user    0m4.102s
sys     0m0.001s

// Shared Quick
real    0m11.328s
user    0m22.420s
sys     0m0.002s
```

While measured with `perf`

```
// Shared Slow
16k cycles
16  cache-misses

// Shared Quick
89k cycles
88  cache-misses
```

The 2 threads are on a separate cpu so they should run pretty independently: 
do you know what could be the reason for this worsening of performance?

I can see that the CPUS are doing a lot of more work compared to the first data structure but I don't understand on what they are busy all that time or where those cycles are spent: do you have any suggestion?

```
#define NTIMES  100000
#define ARRSIZE 10000


void* writer_a(void* args)
{
  cpu_set_t cpu;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpu);
  CPU_SET(0, &cpu);
  pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu);

  Shared* p = (Shared*)args;

  for(int j=0;j<NTIMES; j++){
  for(int i=0;i<ARRSIZE;i++){
    p[i].a_ = j;
    p[i].a_ += j;
    p[i].d_ = p[i].a_;
    p[i].d_ += j;
  }
  }
  return 0;
}

void* writer_b(void* args)
{
  cpu_set_t cpu;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpu);
  CPU_SET(15, &cpu);
  pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu);      

  Shared* p = (Shared*)args;

  for(int j=0;j<NTIMES; j++){
  for(int i=0;i<ARRSIZE;i++){
    p[i].b_ = j;
    p[i].b_ += j;
    p[i].c_ = p[i].b_;
    p[i].c_ += j;
  }
  }
}

//typedef SharedSlow Shared;
typedef SharedQuick  Shared;  // this goes very slow

int main()
{
  pthread_t first, second;
  int ret = 0;

  Shared* p = new Shared[ARRSIZE];
  ret = pthread_create(&first,NULL, writer_a, p);
  if(ret != 0){
    cout << "err" << __LINE__ << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ret = pthread_create(&second,NULL, writer_b, p);
  if(ret !=0){
    cout << "err" << __LINE__ << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  void *r1, *r2;
  pthread_join(first,  &r1);
  pthread_join(second, &r2);        
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The OP is trying to test for false-sharing. That will only happen if two different threads try to access the same cache line where at least one of them is a write.

Comment: How big is `ARRSIZE`? Does it fit into L1 cache?

Comment: Hi. Thinking better this might not be the right test to assess false sharing. ARRSIZE is big number and the threads looping each time from the first to the last probably will cause the cache eviction. The 2 threads cannot perfectly synchronized to be on the same cache line so I believe that they just retrieve the structure from memory indipendently. 2 cache line separate means also double the work (like Joachim was saying..did he deleted the response?) for CPU.

Comment: @Mystical: I've fixed the code as I left a piece of the code out. ARRAYSIZE is 10000